# Having trouble sending array as API response from Express to Front End. Any suggestions?

Tags: node.js, json, express, vue.js

I'm new to Express / APIs, and I'm trying to send an array of JSON objects through from server to client...here is a simple example:

**Server-side (Express, router file)**

```
router.get('/test', function(req, res, next) {
  var testData = ["{'field' : 'a'}", "{'field' : 'b'}", "{'field' : 'c'}"]
  console.log(testData)
  res.send(testData)
})
```

First I stringify the JSONs and then stitch them together in an array before sending the response... now on the client side...

**Client-side (Vue, getTest is triggered by a button and I just check the log for now)**

```
methods : {
    getTest: async () => {
      let testData = await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/test',[])
      console.log(testData)
    }
  }
```

Here I pull the array of JSONs from the API and just want to see them in the console. This only returns an empty string as follows:

```
{data: "", status: 200, statusText: "OK", headers: {…}, config: {…}, …}
```

Any ideas? Apologies if I am missing something basic.
Note that I won't know the length of the array I'm sending from the API ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can do on the server side is using `res.json()` insted of `res.send()` for json response

EDIT : Here a link to the documentation
https://expressjs.com/fr/api.html#res.json

Answer (score 0):

first can you tell what each of these "console.log"s outputed so we could debug it ?
I put your API in my own express server and i got this response which is fine

```
0   "{'field' : 'a'}"
1   "{'field' : 'b'}"
2   "{'field' : 'c'}"
```

and fetched it in my Vue app and got this response:

```
    config: Object { url: "http://localhost:3000/test", method: "get", timeout: 0, … }
​
data: (3) […]
​​
0: "{'field' : 'a'}"
​​
1: "{'field' : 'b'}"
​​
2: "{'field' : 'c'}"
​​
length: 3
​​
<prototype>: Array []
​
headers: Object { "content-type": "application/json; charset=utf-8" }
​
request: XMLHttpRequest { readyState: 4, timeout: 0, withCredentials: false, … }
​
status: 200
​
statusText: "OK"
```

so from what i see everything is ok in your code; I don't think you need to change anything in your code. it might be something with your configuration, which again if you tell us what your apps log we might find out the problem.

Comment: Thank you so much for helping with this. The server side console says: '[ "{'field' : 'a'}", "{'field' : 'b'}", "{'field' : 'c'}" ]
GET /test 200 3.749 ms - -'

On the client side it looks similar to your log, only the data field is an empty string. 

config: {url: "http://localhost:3000/test", method: "get", headers: {…}, transformRequest: Array(1), transformResponse: Array(1), …}
data: ""
status: 200
statusText: "OK"

Comment: Interestingly, when I navigate to localhost:3000/test I see no errors but there is no data sent to the response. Just a blank screen. Res.send('test') displays 'test' at that page and Res.send({'a':'test'}) correctly displays the json. But when I do Res.send(['a','b']) I get nothing in the response.

Comment: After messing around a bit more, I've tried: res.send({ 'b': ['a'] }), which actually sends something, but not what I expected. Log :::: {"b":{"b":"a"}} But if I change it slightly to res.send({ 'whyisntthisworking': ['a'] }), it no longer works.

Comment: i see you have used here `res.send(testData)`  and I did the same thing in my code which worked fine because you're sending the testData variable which is an array of objects.
I don't understand how can your code work fine with me but it doesn't work for you.
I can't think of anything to solve this. but just know that your code is fine. It must be in your express configurations or something.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try to change your method on frontend like this?

```
methods : {
    getTest: async () => {
      // use promise instead
      await axios.get('http://localhost:3000/test',[]).then((resp) => {
        let testData = resp.data
        console.log(testData)
      }).catch((err) => {
        console.log('oopss..')
      })
    }
  }
```